# Error: "Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'" when trying to create iframe in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, iframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am getting the error:

```
Refused to frame 'http://localhost:8888/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

When trying to create an iframe from a local HTML file that contains an iframe of another local HTML file.

For example `test-outer.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" id="0" src="./test-inner.html" width="100" height="100"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

With the Jupyter Notebook Python code:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame(src='test-outer.html', width=200, height=200)
```

`test-inner.html` could contain anything.

**`test-outer.html` loads perfectly on a separate browser tab. The issue is loading it inside Jupyter Notebook.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is an old question, but to help new seekers.

You need to add headers in your jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings={'headers': {'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors self https://my-website-url.com/jupyter "}}
```

`https://my-website-url.com/jupyter` is the url where you're loading jupyter notebooks in `iFrame`.

> This works in Firefox and Chrome. Not tested in Safari.

Comment: I confirm this solves the problem, should be accepted as the answer